# IE10 - hover triggers unwanted :hover event

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In the jsfiddle included below, there are two hover forms in the footer. When you hover over "login", the login form appears as expected. However, hover over the username input box, and the registration form appears. Also, hover over "register" in the footer, and the registration form appears as expected. However, move the mouse over the "Username" label, and the login form displays.

I'm only getting this error in Internet Explorer (I'm using version 10). Chrome and FireFox have been tested. When I go into compatibility view in IE, I no longer have this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/LcPqR/4/

```
<body>  

<div id="header">
</div>


<div id="middle">
<div id="content"> 
</div><!--/content-->
</div><!--/middle-->

<div id="footer">
<ul id="footer_row">

    <li>login
<ul>
<li ><form name="loginForm" action="redirect.php" method="post">
    <label for="inputUser">Username</label> <input id="inputUser" type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" />
    <label for="inputPass">Password</label> <input id="inputPass" type="password" name="pass" maxlength="254" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="yes"> <label for="chkRemember" />Stay signed in</label>
    <input type="submit" class="submit-form" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</li>
</ul>

</li>
<li>register
<ul>
<li ><form name="registerForm" action="register.php" method="post">
    <label for="inputUser" >Username</label> <input id="inputUser"  type="text" name="user" maxlength="30" />
    <label for="inputEmail" >E-Mail Address</label> <input id="inputEmail" type="text" name="email" maxlength="254" />
    <label for="inputPass1" >Password</label> <input id="inputPass1" type="password" name="pass1" maxlength="254" />
    <label for="inputPass2" >Password (again)</label> <input id="inputPass2" type="password" name="pass2" maxlength="254" />
    <input class="submit-form" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</li>
</ul>


</li></ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: its becouse u have same ids - inputUser and InputPass ... rename them in login or register form and it will be ok

Comment: Wow, looks obvious now. Thank you for pointing it out.